# Two jQuery plugins outputting to same div not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using two jQuery plugins on the same page, namely jflickrfeed and bxSlider. jflickrfeed pulls my 10 most recent photo thumbnails from flickr and puts them into a div, and bxSlider takes the contents of the div and scrolls them in a nice ticker fashion. They work seperately when on the same page, but when I try and make them work together on the same div, bxSlider just seems to give up.

This is in the head of the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="setup.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#slider2').bxSlider({
displaySlideQty: 10,
ticker: true,
tickerSpeed: 3000,
tickerHover: true,
});
});
</script>
```

setup.js contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slider2').jflickrfeed({
        limit: 10,
        qstrings: {
            id: '22264049@N00', tags: 'gigsw, peoplew, miscw, lomow', tagmode: 'any'
        },
        itemTemplate: '<div><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image_s}}" alt="{{title}}" border=0 /></a></div>'
    });
});
```

and the body just contains

```
<div id="slider2"></div>
```

And I'll just link to the other two as they are pretty lengthy with all the optional bits.

Can anyone help with getting these two to work together?

Comment: If I were you, I probably wouldn't have both `$(function() {});` and `$(document).ready(function() {});` since they are both valid entry points for the script to execute. I'm not positive, but perhaps the slider is trying to work before the flickrfeed has executed or finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used these plugins, but it looks like the flickr one supports a callback function. Perhaps you should use that to apply the slider when loaded.

```
$(function(){
     var jflckoptions = {...};
     var jflcktemplate = "...";
     var bxoptions = {...};
     $("#slider2").jflickrfeed(jflckoptions,jflcktemplate,function() { $("#slider2").bxSlider(bxoptions); });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've never worked with *jflickrfeed* or *bxSlider*.

I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that your slider code is running immediately when the page loads, which is happening before the jQuery document ready handler is firing and executing the flickr code. Therefore, the slider is initializing itself before it sees any/all the photos in the slider `<div>`.

Try to make sure that your slider plugin gets initialized ***after*** the flickr function finishes executing.